# How to fix this exercise with Endomorphic wrapper?

Tags: xml, scalaz, kleisli

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379707/composing-functions-that-return-an-option).

Suppose I need to find an XML node by path. I can write a function to get a child node by name

```
import scala.xml.{Node => XmlNode}

def child(name: String): XmlNode = Option[XmlNode] = _.child.find(_.label == name)
```

I compose the `child` functions with kleisli; e.g.

```
scala> val a = <a><a0><a1><a2/></a1></a0></a>
a: scala.xml.Elem = <a><a0><a1><a2/></a1></a0></a>

scala> val find01 = Kleisli(child("a0")) >=> Kleisli(child("a1"))
findAB: scalaz.Kleisli[Option,scala.xml.Node,scala.xml.Node] = Kleisli(<function1>)

scala> find01(a)
res85: Option[scala.xml.Node] = Some(<a1><a2/></a1>)
```

Now I am using the endomorphic wrapper but it doesn't work:

```
 scala> List(child("a0"), child("a1")).foldMap(Endomorphic.endoKleisli[Option, XmlNode])
 res93: scalaz.Endomorphic[[α, β]scalaz.Kleisli[Option,α,β],scala.xml.Node] = Endomorphic(Kleisli(<function1>))

 scala> res93.run(a)
 res94: Option[scala.xml.Node] = None
```

Could you help to find the bug ?

Comment: What happens when you swap them around? `List(child("a1"), child("a0")).foldMap(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you are composing left-to-right (`>=>`).

But [`Endomorphic` calls the `compose` method](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/c847654dcf75c748eacbaf246511bbd938b8631f/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Endomorphic.scala#L58) (a.k.a. `<=<`), which works right-to-left.

So your second example would capture `<a1>` first, then look for `<a0>` inside that, which clearly fails.

There are two ways to recover the left-to-right behavior. You can reverse the list before folding it, or wrap each element in a [`Dual`](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Tags$$Dual).

Comment: Thank you. I see it now. Unfortunately I do not understand why the  `append` of the  `Endomorphic` semigroup calls `compose` aka `<=<` instead of `>=>`. I think you need `>=>` in most cases.

Comment: Do you any idea why they implement it this way ? Can you think about any example ?

Comment: @Michael function application in general works right-to-left. For example, the expression `f(g(x))` would call `g` first, then call `f` on the result. The `compose` method is consistent with this idea.