# Why is there no >=> semigroup for A => M[A] in Scalaz?

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli, semigroup

This is a followup to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401343/how-to-fix-this-exercise-with-endomorphic-wrapper)

`Kleisli` defines two operators `<=<` (compose) and `>=>` (andThen). The `>=>` looks very natural for me and I don't understand how `<=<` can be useful.

Moreover, it looks like there is no `>=>` semigroup for `A => M[A]` but the `<=<` semigroup does exist.

What is the rationale behind it ?

Comment: I suspect the only real answer is mathematical tradition. The two are equivalent in that `a <=< b == b >=> a`, no? So it's just a convention, like e.g. matrix multiplication being defined as row-column rather than column-row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`compose` (or `<=<`) is a little more natural when translating between point-free and non point-free styles. For example, if we have these functions:

```
val f: Int => Int = _ + 1
val g: Int => Int = _ * 10
```

We get the following equivalences:

```
scala> (f andThen g)(3) == g(f(3))
res0: Boolean = true

scala> (f compose g)(3) == f(g(3))
res1: Boolean = true
```

In the `compose` case the `f` and `g` are in the same order on both sides of the equation.

Unfortunately Scala's type inference often makes `andThen` (or `>=>`) more convenient, and it tends to be more widely used than `compose`. So this is a case where mathematical conventions and the quirks of Scala's type inference system are at odds. Scalaz (not too surprisingly, given the culture of the project) chooses the math side.

Comment: Thanks, I see the point. I am wondering, how to implement smth. like that: suppose I have a function `child(name: String): XmlNode => Option[XmlNode]`. I would like to write `List("a", "b", "c").map(name => child(name)).foldMap(...)` to get a function that return a node by path `"a/b/c"`. And now I need to reverse the list :( which seems completely redundant.`

Comment: Yeah, that's a case where `>=>` does seem to correspond more closely to what the operation does. I'd probably skip the monoid and use `>=>` directly.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be possible just to define such a monoid: `Monoid.instance(_ >=> _, {node => Some(node)})` (not sure how to do it right yet) and pass it to the `foldMap`. I will probably ask a new question about it.