# Are there interesting examples of composing Kleisli endomorphisms?

Tags: scala, scalaz, kleisli

This is a follow-up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401343/how-to-fix-this-exercise-with-endomorphic-wrapper)

We can define a function that finds an XML node by path `(List[String], XmlNode) => Option[XmlNode]` as a composition of functions `(String, XmlNode) => Option[XmlNode]` that get a child node by name.

We use the fact that functions `A => M[A]`, where `M` is a monad, form a `monoid` and so we can easily compose them.

Now I wonder whether there are other interesting examples of composing such functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

knight’s quest example from learning Scalaz

http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/A-knights-quest.html

before

```
def in3: List[KnightPos] =
  for {
    first <- move
    second <- first.move
    third <- second.move
  } yield third

def canReachIn3(end: KnightPos): Boolean = in3 contains end
```

after(use scalaz.Endomorphic)

```
val moveK: Kleisli[List, KnightPos, KnightPos] = Kleisli(_.move)

def in(n: Int): List[KnightPos] =
  moveK.endo.multiply(n).run.run(this)

def canReachIn(n: Int, end: KnightPos): Boolean = in(n) contains end
```

https://gist.github.com/xuwei-k/c77aa4e19c0b4d4c10e2/revisions

Comment: Nice example. Thanks.